# How to get list of employee along with their reimbursement amount for their trip

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to get a list of employee names and their reimbursement amount for their trip.

Rule: Employees are eligible for reimbursement only when their origin is same as destination in return trip.

**Input: Table name: Reimbursement**

```
  Name      From_station      To_station         Amount
    Hari    Bengaluru         Hyderabad    2500
    Hari    Hyderabad         Bengaluru    2600
    Raju    Chennai           Pune         3400
    Raju    Pune              Hyderabad    2000
    Kiran   Kerala            Chennai      2300
    Kiran   Chennai           Kerala       3200
```

**Output:**

```
Name        Reimbursement_amount
Hari        5100
Kiran       5500
```

**Query**:

```
select p.name, amount 
      from(select name,
                  min(from_station) as from_station,
                  min(to_station) as to_station,
                  sum(amount) as amount 
           from reimbursement r1 group by name) p 
where p.from_station = p.to_station 
order by name;
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Try: `select name, sum(amount) as total from reimbursement group by name`

Comment: @Martin . . . (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Can a trip have more than two legs?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  (1) The DB is Oracle, (2) . trip can't have more than two legs

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross join to check to and from destination between rows of a specific user and keep records only with your matching logic.

**Note**: Better if you can use User_id instead of Name as there may have more than one user with same name.

```
SELECT A.Name, SUM(A.Amount) Reimbursement_amount
FROM Reimburment A
CROSS JOIN Reimburment B
WHERE A.From_station = B.To_station AND A.To_station = B.From_station
AND A.Name = B.Name
GROUP BY A.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with EXISTS:

```
select 
  t.Name, 
  sum(t.Amount) Reimbursement_amount
from Reimburment t
where exists (
  select 1 from Reimburment
  where Name = t.Name and From_station = t.To_station and To_station = t.From_station
)
group by t.Name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2t71ghgFw9itJBdxs6ggSh/0).
Results:

```
| Name  | Reimbursement_amount |
| ----- | -------------------- |
| Hari  | 5100                 |
| Kiran | 5500                 |
```

Answer (score -1):

mosdt dbms suppout analytic function first_value and last_value i have used to take name wise 1st value of from station and last value of to station and compare them for getting in selection for reinbersement

```
 with reimbursement as
(
select 'Hari' as name, 'Bengaluru' as From_station , 'Hyderabad' as To_station, 2500 as amount
union all
select 'Hari','Hyderabad','Bengaluru',2600
union all
select 'Raju','Chennai','Pune',3400
union all
select 'Raju','Pune','Hyderabad',2000 
union all
select 'Kiran','Kerala','Chennai',2300
union all
select 'Kiran','Chennai','Kerala',3200
),cte as
(
select *,row_number()over(partition by name order by From_station) rn
from reimbursement
), cte1 as
 (select name,amount,
 FIRST_VALUE(From_station) over(partition by name order by rn) as f,
 LAST_VALUE(To_station) over(partition by name  order by rn desc) t
 from cte
 )select name , sum(amount) AS TOTAL 
 FROM reimbursement WHERE name IN (
 select name 
 from cte1 where f=t
 ) GROUP BY NAME
```

[oneline demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=768f433131eb4bffbed477f27a87bf4d)

```
name    TOTAL
Hari    5100
Kiran   5500
```